# Form upload using jQuery (GWT)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt, jsni

I need to be able to do form upload with GWT without redirecting or refreshing the page, however my codes does not redirect anymore, it still refresh and the alert box does not popup:

```
public static native void showUploadModal(String title, String hash)/*-{
        var target = '/files/" + hash + "/';
        $wnd.$("<div></div>")
            .html("<form id='form_upload' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><p>Select a file: <input type='file' name='file'/></p><input type='submit' id='form_submit' value='Attach'></form>")
            .appendTo("body")
            .dialog({
                title: title,
                modal: true,
                width: 400,
                hide: "fade",
                show: "fade",
                buttons: {
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $wnd.$(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });    
        $wnd.$('#form_submit').submit(function() {
            // the script where you handle the form input.
            var url = '/files/" + hash + "/'; 
            $wnd.$.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: $wnd.$('#form_upload').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       alert(data); // show response 
                   }
                 });
            return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });         
    }-*/;
```

What could be the problem with this code?

Comment: any client or server errors?  Does it get into this code?

Comment: Yes, the method is called when button is clicked. It basically shows a modal dialog which then renders the form upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few details that are a little odd here:

```
var target = '/files/" + hash + "/';

var url = '/files/" + hash + "/';
```

These two lines set the value of their variable to `/files/" + hash + "/`, including the `+` and the text `hash`, not the value of the variable. Probably not what you had in mind. The `target` variable doesn't appear to be used, but `url` is.

Next:

```
alert(data); // show response
```

Instead, you probably mean `$wnd.alert(data);`

Finally, with a url like `http://server.com/files/" + hash + "/` is probably not sending back a success code, so the success callback might not be being called at all - be sure to set a failure callback too.